# Unable to inject livedata repository class using Dagger2

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-livedata

I have an Android project which is using Dagger 2, Livedata and viewmodel, rxjava and databinding.

I have created an AppComponent and two SubComponents as of now. The Appcomponent is for applicationscope and one Subcomponent that is ControllerComponent is for Activity, fragments and dialogs. This ControllerComponent is injected in the baseactivity and it is working fine.

The other Sub component is RetrofitComponent which is for viewmodel repositories. Now I can't seem to find a way to inject the retrofit component in the base repository since it is a Subcomponent and I don't have the applicationcontext in the repository class.

AppComponent:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {
    ApplicationModule.class,
    PrefModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {
  public void inject(AppInstance appInstance);

  public AppPreference getAppPref();

  public Application getApplication();

  public ControllerComponent newControllerComponent(ControllerModule controllerModule);

  public RetrofitComponent newRetrofitComponent(RetrofitModule retrofitModule);
}
```

RetrofitComponent:

```
@RepositoryScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {RetrofitModule.class})
public interface RetrofitComponent {
  public void inject(BaseRepo baseRepo);

  public APICall getApiCalls();
}
```

RetrofitModule:

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {
  @Provides
  @RepositoryScope
  public APICall providePostApi(Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(APICall.class);
  }

  @Provides
  @RepositoryScope
  public Retrofit provideRetrofitInterface() {
    return new RetrofitService().retrofit;
  }
}
```

BaseRepo;

```
@Inject
public APICall apiCall;

private Disposable subscription;
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

private RetrofitComponent injector;

public BaseRepo() {
    //injector = DaggerRetrofitComponent.builder().retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule()).build();(I tried with dependent component had different problem)
    injector = ((AppInstance)getApplication()).getAppComponent().newRetrofitComponent(new RetrofitModule());(Not able to use getApplication())
    injector.inject(this);
}
```

I'm going to use the child repositories extending this base repository from their corresponding viewmodels so I don't intend to pass on the application from the activities or fragments.

What I might be missing? Or doing wrong? Or is my approach wrong?

And one more thing once this is done, should I inject the repository classes in the Viewmodel class or should I create a factory class and call whichever repository I need, which is better practice?

Comment: do you still need help with this?

Comment: @WhileTrue somewhat yes, but now my problem has grown too.